# Cannot Create More than 1 Class Instance with Python

Tags: python

```
# Creates a Dot Instance.
class Dot(object):
    velx=0
    vely=0
    def __init__(self, xloc=0, yloc=0,color=(0,7,0)):
        self.color=color
        self.xloc=xloc
        self.yloc=xloc

    def entity(self):
     for event in pygame.event.get():
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, (self.color), (self.xloc,self.yloc, 50, 50))
        pygame.display.update()


GameExit=False

# Main Function
def Main():
    global x,y,gameDisplay
    Red=Dot(50,50,color=(0,0,255))
    Blue=Dot(150,150,color=(255,0,0))
    Red.entity()
    Blue.entity()

    pygame.display.update()
    while not GameExit:
        if GameExit==False:
            pygame.QUIT

Main()
```

Im trying to create a second class instance that will display a Red Dot but it doesn't seem to be appearing. The first class instance works and it creates a Blue Dot on the Display. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Name your variable with lowercase please : Red, Blue

Comment: As a better suggestion - follow https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: @BłażejMichalik no, you are correct, I just read it incorrectly, did not see the assignment statements, speaking of PEP8 formatting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def entity(self):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, self.color, (self.xloc, self.yloc, 50, 50))
    pygame.display.update()
```

**See it in online REPL with pyGame:** https://repl.it/repls/ActiveMisguidedApplescript

---

The problem stems from implementation of `.entity()`.

In your code:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    ...
```

You are essentially drawing stuff only if there's an event in the queue.
So the call to `Red.entity()` exhausts this queue. The call to `Blue.entity()` doesn't even enter the aforementioned for loop, as there's nothing to iterate on at that particular moment - `pygame.event.get()` returns an empty list.

---

From [pygame.event.get() docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get):

> This will get all the messages and remove them from the queue.

---

Also, your event loop looks wrong. It should be (in `Main`):

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            return
```